# API Change error when building AOSP 5.1

Tags: android, android-source

Currently trying to build android-5.1.0_r5. I've checked out the sources and made no modifications. However, when compiling I get the following error.

```
Checking API: checkpublicapi-current
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:20: error 5: Added public field android.Manifest.permission.BACKUP
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:82: error 5: Added public field android.Manifest.permission.INVOKE_CARRIER_SETUP
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:106: error 5: Added public field android.Manifest.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:116: error 5: Added public field android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_EMERGENCY_BROADCAST

******************************
You have tried to change the API from what has been previously approved.

To make these errors go away, you have two choices:
   1) You can add "@hide" javadoc comments to the methods, etc. listed in the
      errors above.

   2) You can update current.txt by executing the following command:
         make update-api

      To submit the revised current.txt to the main Android repository,
      you will need approval.
******************************
```

And diffing the public api txt files does indeed show a difference.

```
diff frameworks/base/api/current.txt out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt 
19a20
>     field public static final java.lang.String BACKUP = "android.permission.BACKUP";
80a82
>     field public static final java.lang.String INVOKE_CARRIER_SETUP = "android.permission.INVOKE_CARRIER_SETUP";
103a106
>     field public static final java.lang.String READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE = "android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE";
112a116
>     field public static final java.lang.String RECEIVE_EMERGENCY_BROADCAST = "android.permission.RECEIVE_EMERGENCY_BROADCAST";
```

However, I cant figure out where those additional Public Fields are coming from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do see the entries in my r8 code so you are probably safe running make update-api, and when that finishes then run your make command as normal.

Answer (score 10):

Don't do 'make update-api' if you didn't touch anything. There additional apis came form frameworks/base/res/AndroidManifest.xml badly parsed by aapt that uses buggy system/core/libcore/String8.cpp@@removeAll() they use memcpy but should be memmove for overlapping strings in memory.

This is issue on latest Debian (sid) or Ubuntu (16 maybe 15) build machines. 
It's a google bug in libcore/String8.cpp. Fix is here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/dd060f01f68ee0e633e9cae24c4e565cda2032bd

This man found it (Michael Scott) and maybe some other people too. Here is his investigation: https://plus.google.com/+hashcode0f/posts/URHo3hBmfHY

> Living on the Edge (of Ubuntu) ... can be painful!
>
> I've been running Ubuntu 15.04 for a while now.  It's been great
>   having a very current kernel alongside the latest improvements from
>   Ubuntu and Debian.  (My past post on using zRAM ramdisk is one
>   example).
>
> However, having the newest greatest toys also has it's downsides.  I
>   recently spent 4 days troubleshooting a build break in Android which
>   started some time after March 25th.  I'm guessing I updated packages
>   or inadvertently changed my glibc version.
>
> The outcome was a build error during the checkapi stage of Android
>   build:
>
> Install: /out/mydroid-ara/host/linux-x86/bin/apicheck Checking API:
>   checkpublicapi-last Checking API: checkpublicapi-current
>   /out/mydroid-ara/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:20: error
>   5: Added public field android.Manifest.permission.BACKUP
>   /out/mydroid-ara/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:82: error
>   5: Added public field android.Manifest.permission.INVOKE_CARRIER_SETUP
>   /out/mydroid-ara/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:106: error
>   5: Added public field
>   android.Manifest.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE
>   /out/mydroid-ara/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:116: error
>   5: Added public field
>   android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_EMERGENCY_BROADCAST
>
> **************************** You have tried to change the API from what has been previously approved.
>
> To make these errors go away, you have two choices:    1) You can add
>   "@hide" javadoc comments to the methods, etc. listed in the
>         errors above.
>
> 2) You can update current.txt by executing the following command:
>            make update-api
>
> ```
>   To submit the revised current.txt to the main Android repository,
>   you will need approval.
> ```
>
> ---
>
> This occurred on both of my Ubuntu 15.04 boxes and was present when
>   when build AOSP android-5.0.2_r1 and android-5.1.0_r1.
>
> For those of you who are unfamiliar with this portion of the Android
>   build, the Android framework exports all of the public portions of the
>   API and makes sure that the current build matches up with what's
>   located under frameworks/base/api/current.txt.  It does this by
>   parsing frameworks/base/res/AndroidManifest.xml and any of the current
>   device's overlay .xml files and processes items marked with various
>   flags in the comments above them:@SystemApi, @hide, etc.   This
>   parsing and processing portion of the checkapi stage is done by a
>   binary "aapt" (Android Asset Packagng Tool).  It's source is located
>   under frameworks/base/tools/aapt.
>
> I started by checking for upstream fixes to the platform/build or
>   platform/frameworks/base projects.   After striking out, I began
>   debugging the android build via the use of: "make checkapi
>   showcommands" and then manually running the commands with "strace" to
>   see how each binary was involved and what output it generated.
>
> After the first few hours of debugging, it became apparent that
>   out/target/common/obj/APPS/frameworks-res_intermediates/src/android/Manifest.java
>   file had comments which were being corrupted when aapt was generating
>   it.  I was able to make some manual changes to the AndroidManifest.xml
>   file and get the build to pass (removing extra portions of the
>   comments).
>
> Digging deeper via strace and then looking at various static link
>   sources, I found that during the AndroidManifest.xml comments
>   processing the @SystemApi token was being filtered out via a
>   String8.removeAll("@SystemApi") function call.  Experimentally, I
>   removed this part of the processing.  Lo and Behold!  The build
>   worked.  Taking a closer look at the removeAll function, I was able to
>   pin point a memcpy function as the part of the function which was
>   causing corruption.
>
> I then researched memcpy a bit and noted that you are not supposed to
>   use memcpy on overlapping memory addresses, instead memmove was
>   preferred, because it makes a copy of the source prior to any changes
>   being made to the destination.  After changing the use of memcpy to
>   memmove the build was fixed and all was well with the world!
>
> As a good player in the open source world, I immediately thought I
>   should upstream this incredible feat of debugging to the master branch
>   of system/core.  BUT, alas!  The fix has been in the master branch
>   since November 11th 2014!  And hasn't been brought into any of the
>   current development tags!  grumble
>   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/dd060f01f68ee0e633e9cae24c4e565cda2032bd
>
> I've since contacted the Google team about this change and let them
>   know of my experience in hopes that we may yet see this patch in
>   future release tags of Android.
>
> Conclusion: apparently glibc is undergoeing some changes and some of
>   those have now filtered onto my Ubuntu boxes.  Where previously the
>   memcpy usage was incorrect but still usable, it now causes the build
>   break I was seeing.
>
> If you see this kind of error in your Android builds, and you're on a
>   newish version of Ubuntu or Debian distrobution, you may want to try
>   this simple patch and see if it helps.
>
> - Hash

Big up himself!

Comment: >Don't do 'make update-api' if you didn't touch anything. 

This seems to be right. But I am on 6.0.1 M4B30Z. But in line 434, it is already 
`        memmove(buf + tail, buf + index + skip, next - index - skip);
`

There seems to be another reason for this issue.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's broken even in 5.1.1. Really annoying that all these years and they never patched this because it breaks the build even back then.