# Building Android 4.3_r1 on Ubuntu 16 LTS Errors

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-source

I am looking for help with the Android AOSP setup for a project. I am trying to build Android 4.3_r1  from source on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial) , I have installed all the dependencies and the oracle Java 6 . The build runs well until one point where I get the following error :

```
******************************
You have tried to change the API from what has been previously 
approved.
To make these errors go away, you have two choices:
   1) You can add "@hide" javadoc comments to the methods, etc. listed 
   in the errors above.
   2) You can update current.txt by executing the following command:
     make update-api
     To submit the revised current.txt to the main Android repository,
     you will need approval.
******************************
```

Tried  removing the current.txt ,redoing the steps from scratch , make update-api also still facing the same error.Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654807/8749619?

Comment: Yes It did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying out several fixes it did not work out for me, so i reinstalled java and the AOSP to get it to work.